# Retrain a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to retrain a tensorflow.keras model, and I tried to compare both models:

Code 1:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-2)
model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[8])])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=3)
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Code 2:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-2)
model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[8])])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=6)
```

In code 1, I get:

```
Epoch 1/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 330us/step - loss: 1.8888
Epoch 2/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 342us/step - loss: 0.5772
Epoch 3/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 397us/step - loss: 0.5508

Epoch 1/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 470us/step - loss: 0.5428
Epoch 2/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 486us/step - loss: 0.5338
Epoch 3/3
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 479us/step - loss: 0.5519
```

In code 2, I get:

```
Epoch 1/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 332us/step - loss: 1.8888
Epoch 2/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 322us/step - loss: 0.5772
Epoch 3/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 333us/step - loss: 0.5508
Epoch 4/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 331us/step - loss: 0.5413
Epoch 5/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 371us/step - loss: 0.5440
Epoch 6/6
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 356us/step - loss: 0.5318
```

If you want to check on your own computer, I use this dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import os

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

housing = fetch_california_housing()
X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(
    housing.data, housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), random_state=42)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
    X_train_full, y_train_full, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid_scaled = scaler.transform(X_valid)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I compared both ways of training a model:

- first is by running 3 epochs, then 3 epochs
- second is by running 6 epochs
  It's unclear where the problem is. I use tensorflow 2.2.2 (or 2.3 provides the same results)

I don't understand why they don't provide the same result.

Comment: Epochs are not independent. Some optimizers (i.e. Adam) use values from previous epochs during training.

Comment: Thank you. How is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: You can try this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/BackupAndRestore.